# Creating a generic function for a function of an animation that I have

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-animate

I am learning Jquery, and I am making my new website. unluckily I am a more of a web designer (with experience more on Design that on Programming) and I am stuck in trying to create a generic function so I can use it for various div elements in the html.

This is the code

```
$(".myCircle").hover(
    // when the mouse enters the box do...
    function(){
        var $box = $(this),
        offset = $box.offset(),
        radius = $box.width() / 2,
        circle = new SimpleCircle(offset.left + radius, offset.top + radius, radius);

        $box.mousemove(function(e){
         if(myHover != "transition1" && circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY)){
             $(this).css({"cursor":"pointer"});
             myHover = "transition1";
                $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"-200px"}, speed/2, function(){
                    myHover = 1;
                });
            }

            else if(!circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY)){
             $(this).css({"cursor":"default"});
                if(myHover == 1 || myHover == "transition1"){
                    myHover = "transition0";
                    $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"0px"}, speed/2, function(){
                        myHover = 0;
                    });
                    $("body").unbind('mousemove');
                }
            }
       });

    },
    // when the mouse leaves the box do...
    function() {       
        if(myHover == 1 || myHover == "transition1"){
            myHover = "transition0";
         $(this).css({"cursor":"default"});
            $("#black").stop().animate({"top":"0px"}, speed/2, function(){
                myHover = 0;
            })
        };
        $("body").unbind('mousemove');
    }
);
```

The animation is a div with radius corner, that looks like a circle, and that with my on mouse hover I activate an animation behind the circle to come out.

What I would like to achive it is not to write all the time the same long function for when I want to use it for multiple div/circle. But re-use a generic function.

a function something like: function circleHover(myCircle, myTarget, eventIn(), eventOut())

where myTarget could be any other element, or even the same myCircle, and eventIn() and eventOut() are nothing else the animation (or anything else) on situations when the mouse enter, and when the mouse leaves.

I am having big trouble in creating in a generic way this

$("#black").stop().animate({"top":"-200px"}, speed/2, function(){
     myHover = 1;
});

I am sorry for my silly question, I really don't know where to look for the answer or where to learn more.

==============================

UPDATE- 1st DEC
at the end I end up with this code. I think that it is halfway of what I wanted.

```
function aniCircle(in_out, myThis, target, endPos, movePos, speed){
    if(typeof speed == "undefined"){speed = speed2};

    if(in_out == 1){
        var $box = myThis,
        offset = $box.offset(),
        radius = $box.width() / 2,
        circle = new SimpleCircle(offset.left + radius, offset.top + radius, radius);

        $box.mousemove(function(e){
            if(myHover != "transition1" && circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY)){
                $(this).css({"cursor":"pointer"});
                myHover = "transition1";

                $(target).stop().animate(movePos, speed, function(){
                    myHover = 1;
                });
            }else if(!circle.includesXY(e.pageX, e.pageY)){
                $(this).css({"cursor":"default"});
                if(myHover == 1 || myHover == "transition1"){
                    myHover = "transition0";
                    $(target).stop().animate(endPos, speed, function(){
                        myHover = 0;
                    });
                    $("body").unbind('mousemove');
                }
            }
        });
    }else if(in_out == 0){
        if(myHover == 1 || myHover == "transition1"){
            myHover = "transition0";
            myThis.css({"cursor":"default"});
            $(target).stop().animate(endPos, speed, function(){
                myHover = 0;
            })
        };
        $("body").unbind('mousemove');
    }
}
```

and recalling the function like this

```
$("#logo").hover(
    // when the mouse enters the box do...
    function(){
        aniCircle(1, $(this), "#black", {"top":"0px"},{"top":"-200px"});
    },
    // when the mouse leaves the box do...
    function() {
        aniCircle(0, $(this), "#black", {"top":"0px"});
    }
);
```

I am having difficulties to add various kind of behaviours, like make an animation of a target with a curve animation (Path plugin - arc, bezier and sin animated curves).

I don't expect to solve this problem, but I would like at least a review of the code on what I could optimise. I feel that the code it is a bit repetitive and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

check out these links:
http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand from that info on how to make generic "$("#black").stop().animate({"top":"-200px"}, speed/2, function(){ myHover = 1; });"

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd simply need to update your targeting within each function so that instead of looking for a node with an id, but rather a node with a class.  So, instead of using $('#black') as the selector, change the `id="black"` to a node with a class - like: `class="black"`.  Then, inside each function, use jQuery's next method to target the next node classed as 'black':

```
$box.next('.black').stop()...
```

You could also continue to develop this into a plugin, but you probably don't need to - it's completely up to you.  What you have (with the updated targeting approach) will work for all elements returned by the $('.myCircle') selector.

Comment: At the end I end up in something halfway that I wanted, because I am not programmaticaly able to do it :( - Check the post I have added an update